# xslt group-adjacent multi node

Tags: xslt-2.0

I would like to group nodes which following-sibling

```
<doc>
    <a>blabla</a>
    <b>blabla</b>
    <c>text C</c>
    <d>text D</d>
    <a>bla</a>
    <d>text D</d>
    <a>bla</a>
</doc>
```

output desired :

```
<doc>
    <a>blabla</a>
    <b>blabla</b>
    <c>text C</c>
<GROUP>
    <d>text D</d>
    <a>bla</a>
    <d>text D</d>
    <a>bla</a>
</GROUP>
</doc>
```

I've tried :

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*"
                group-adjacent="boolean(self::a | self::d)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:element name="GROUP">
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

How can i do to exclude a not preceding-sibling::*[1]=d ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've found :

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*"
            group-adjacent="self::a or self::d
            [following-sibling::*[1][self::a or self::d]
            or
            (preceding-sibling::*[1][self::a or self::d])
            ]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and current-group()[2]">
                    <xsl:element name="GROUP">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).